Prove the round down of $e\cdot k!=\sum_{0}^{k}\frac{k!}{j!}$
I am trying to prove the lower bound for Ramsey number $R_k(3,3, \dots, 3)$. I want to show $\lfloor e\cdot k!\rfloor=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{k!}{j!}$. The trick is expand $e$ as infinite series but I do not know why the tail $\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{j!}<1$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational

For $k\geq 2,\ \displaystyle\sum_{j=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{k!}{j!} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)^n} = \frac{1}{(k+1)-1} = \frac{1}{k} <1$.
